# How can I start an action from inside a Google calendar event?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, calendar, event-handling, dom-events

I have a Google script that parses email notifications from my local library about due dates and pick-up notices, then creates calendar events on a Google calendar.  It's not professional code, but it works and is serviceable enough for the family.

I would like to add a feature that allows one to open a calendar event, click on something (like a button or link) and an event that spans 5 days will get shortened to end on the day it is clicked.  The calendar page gets pretty full with 5-day-long events that may have been picked up on the first day.  I need to keep the event on the calendar, because it also serves as a history of checkouts that the library does not keep.

I can kluge together the logic to do the event manipulation, but it's the firing off that process that is stumping me.  I've seen Google spreadsheet usage as a backend db-like service, but that really feels like using Access back in school, so I'd like to find a different approach.